# SetContentView does not work while I'm using handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I am trying to make app sleep using `Thread`. I have got 2 solutions but one of them causes a problem.

This is a shorter code which works perfectly:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        final Handler goToMenu = new Handler();

        goToMenu.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        },5000);
}
```

But this one is problematic. When I put the time in millis to make app wait it works and the second Activity starts but the `R.layout.welcome` does not appear. The app just waits with a gray background until the `startActivity(i)` gets executed.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        final Handler goToMenu = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };

        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait(5000);
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "Waiting didnt work!!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                goToMenu.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            }

        };

        Thread waitThread = new Thread(run);
        waitThread.run();
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a new thread, use `Thread#start()` and not `Thread#run()`.

`run()` just executes the `Runnable` synchronously i.e. blocking the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){}, DELAY_TIME) instead
```

for your case

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
         startActivity(i);
      }
 }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To Show thelayout, Activity's `onCreate()` method should run completely. In your second code there is a thread. That thread stops your code compilation for 5000 milliseconds. That means your second code stops and wait 5 seconds in `wait(5000);` line. Therefore `onCreate()` method not completes.

You have used `Handler().postDelayed()` your first code. This method don't stuck the code. It is a background task. it works synchronously.

I hope your answer is here.